# Enabling ace editor autocomplete for methods only if the right scopes are typed in

Tags: autocomplete, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor to enable autocomplete for custom snippets I've loaded into ace/snippets through a method. However, I want various snippets to pop up in autocomplete only after the user has typed in the correct scopes which will then trigger said snippets.

Currently, I have guards set up in regex form in the snippets themselves, but this does not seem to be working.
[Example of what a loaded snippet object looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYEe1.png)

Are guard functions effective enough to trigger the snippets properly or do I have to modify something within the ace.define functions?

```
  var editor = ace.edit("aceTextEditorContainer");
  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/textmate");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/gameblox");


  ace.require("ace/config").set("workerPath", "path/to/ace");
    // editor.session.setOption("useWorker", true);

  ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");

  editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;

  editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true
 });
```

I do have this currently.
I load the snippets through this function:

```
ace.config.loadModule("ace/snippets/gameblox", function() {


if (window.snippetArray) {
    snippetManager.files.gameblox = {};
    snippetManager.files.gameblox["scope"] = "gameblox";
    snippetManager.files.gameblox["snippetText"] = ace.require("ace/snippets/gameblox").snippetText;
    snippetManager.files.gameblox["snippets"] = [];
    snippetManager.files.gameblox.snippets.concat(ace.require("ace/snippets/gameblox").snippets);
    for (var i=0; i<window.snippetArray.length; i++){
      var m = window.snippetArray[i].name;
      if (window.snippetArray[i].arguments){
        m += window.snippetArray[i].arguments;
      } 
      var f = snippetArray[i].function;
      if (window.snippetArray[i].possibleScopes){
        var sGuard = snippetArray[i].possibleScopes;// + "[.]" + f;
        var sScope = "scope:gameblox \n\ \n\ WWWuuuutttt \n\ snippet "+m +" \n\  "+ f+ " \n\ ";
        snippetManager.files.gameblox.snippetText += sScope;
        var aScope = {name:m,content:f, trigger:sGuard + "[.]" + f.split("(")[0]};//,tabTrigger:sGuard,guard:sGuard, trigger:sGuard, endTrigger:sGuard, endGuard: sGuard};
        snippetManager.files.gameblox.snippets.push(aScope);
      } else {
        var sNoScope = "scope:gameblox \n\ \n\ WWWuuuutttt \n\ snippet "+m +" \n\  "+f + " \n\ ";
        snippetManager.files.gameblox.snippetText += sNoScope;
        var a = {name:m,content:f,tabTrigger:f};
        snippetManager.files.gameblox.snippets.push(a);  
      }       
    }
    snippetManager.register(snippetManager.files.gameblox.snippets, snippetManager.files.gameblox.scope);
  }
});
```

For example, I want the snippet in the picture linked below to only appear when the appropriate entity/scope is typed in the editor. The appropriate scopes are not static and are updated regularly based on what the user has generated, so hardcoding this is not an option.
Now, it pops up regardless.
[Example of autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnzQw.png)
Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: seeing examples of snippets, and source code where they should be applied would help to better understand your question

Comment: Thank you. I added more information in my question. I hope my question is more understandable now.

Comment: Why are these snippets? they are not meant to be used by just pressing tab key without the popup, right?. I think you need to create a new autocompleter instead

Comment: They pop up and are autocompleted when the tab key is pressed. But I only want them to pop up under various circumstances. Is this not the function of snippets?

Comment: i think you need to add a new autocompleter